# What's the better way to get form data in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor

Example 1:

```
var subject = template.find('input[name="fieldname"').value;
```

Example 2:

```
var subject = event.target.fieldName.value;
```

Is there a preffered way in meteor which one of these you should use? I saw both in two different, recommended tutorials and I am wondering, which is the better one.

Comment: idk but the second is more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var subject = event.target.fieldName.value;
```

Just think about it.

In example 1, you're accessing the template, then you have to find an `input` that has an `attribute` name of "`fieldname`" (the more inputs the longer this part takes), then you access the `value`.

In example 2, you have the event. You access the target and access the fieldName and you get the value.

It's much shorter, and it is just pure JS, so it'll be faster.
So use example 2.